# Nested Attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Imagine 4 models in Rails 3.1

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :courses, :through => :memberships
    has_many :tests, :through => :courses
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ActiveRecod::Base
   has_many :tests 
   has_many :students, :through => :memberships
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :course
end
```

How can I output a sorted list (ie by date) of a student's upcoming tests
(I'm guessing there is a fairly simple answer, but I've been trying in vain for a while)

My best guess is something like:

```
@upcomingTests = @currstudent.tests.sort_by &:testDateTime
```

but it seems to return an empty array

Comment: Please post your best attempt and the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an slight error on your model "Course".  It needs "belongs_to :student".

```
class Course < ActiveRecod::Base
   has_many :tests 
   has_many :students, :through => :memberships
   belongs_to :student
end
```

After you've created and populated a foreign key, you can create a simple named_scope on your test mode:

```
named_scope :ordered, :order => "created_at DESC"
```

Then it's just the matter of accessing it from wherever you want:

```
@ordered_tests = @student.tests.ordered
```